# Pivot Command fails on Multi Parameter CLR Aggregate Function... ideas why?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a couple of `AGGREGATE` functions in CLR

`abj.median`

`abj.percentile`

A bit of an interesting issue.  The functions, in structure , are very similar other than a small difference in the way the results are calculated `AND`, `PERCENTILE` requires 2 parameters, while median only one.

The common parameter on both functions is the field name.  The percentile function also carries a value to determine which percentile (10, 75, 90 etc.....)

This command works fine.....

```
;
WITH p1 AS (

SELECT WAITTIMES_DAY / 7.0 AS waitWeeks, 

abj.fyq(surg_sx_date) as fiscalYear, 

SURG_SITE_ZONE

FROM dbo.Surgery
)

SELECT *

FROM p1 p

PIVOT (abj.median(waitweeks) 

FOR fiscalYear IN ( [2013/14-Q1], [2013/14-Q2], [2013/14-Q3], [2013/14-Q4] )) b
```

---

This command fails with `INCORRECT SYNTAX NEAR '90'.  Expecting '.', ID, or QUOTED_ID.`

```
;
WITH p1 AS (

SELECT WAITTIMES_DAY / 7.0 AS waitWeeks, 

abj.fyq(surg_sx_date) as fiscalYear, 

SURG_SITE_ZONE

FROM dbo.Surgery
)
SELECT *

FROM p1 p

PIVOT (abj.percentile(waitweeks,90) 

FOR fiscalYear IN ( [2013/14-Q1], [2013/14-Q2], [2013/14-Q3], [2013/14-Q4] )) b
```

---

Has anybody ran into this Wierdness before, and how did they fix (other than to breakdown and write the PERCENTILE function with only one parameter, with the second changed to default of 90)

Thanks

Sven

Comment: Will be great if you can post sql to create the tables and add some sample rows. Also see - SQL fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `CLR` functions you use them as is. If function `abj.median` was written to use only one parameter. It will works like this and only like this. If you want that `median` was able to use 2 parameters you need ask developer of this function rewrite it for you.

Comment: Umm, the issue is not passing to many parameters to the MEDIAN command (I wrote BTW).  The issue is that I also wrote a PERCENTILE command in CLR, that takes two parameters.  The only difference between the two functions is that the PERCENTILE allows you to say which percentile you want (e.g. 90) whereas a median is actually the 50th Percentile.  Anyways.  In my code, the question was about why a CLR function with 2 parameters fails on the PIVOT command.  As it turns it out, it is a known problem...:)

Comment: Sad I can't remove this as an answer, because it definitely does not look like one.... :(